# VSTS - build one of many projects from solution

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to centralize in a same VisualStudio solution a lot of projects:
- API.Core (library class)
- API.Mobile (.NET Core project)
- API.Web (.NET Core project)
- Database (SQL Server Database Project)
- Functions (Azure Functions)

For each project except the library classes, I want to configure a build definition but I'd like to trigger the build if and only if I changed a portion of code of a project. Ex: I made some modifications in API.Web => so I want the build definition of API.Web to trigger only and not the others.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Before giving the detail solutions, can you provider more detail information: 1. What the version control system do you use to manage your code, Git or TFVC? 2. Can you show the file structures of your repo?

Answer (score 0):

When setting up CI, you can setup a Path filter. this will result in the build only triggering when files are changed in that specific path[image]

Comment: How do you do this for Git in Azure devops? then you only can choos branch. not path...

Comment: This is supported for both TFVC as well as Git (the example above is actually using a git repo). It should also work for external (i.e GitHub) repos. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is using multiple build definitions, each build definition for a project.

Then as Remco said that, set the Path filters for each project in the build definition, 
then specify the corresponding project file or /t:{project} msbuild argument to just build the related project.

For example,

Build definition name: BuildDefForAPICore

Path filter: the path for API.Core project folder

Choose API.Core.csproj file in Visual Studio Build task.